# 12.04 LTS will no longer download updates

Tags: 12.04, updates, 64-bit

The machine is a newish one using the 64 version. It has always updated OK but now I get the message:

```
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager-core_0.156.14.16_amd64.deb 404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/update-manager/update-manager_0.156.14.16_all.deb 404  Not Found
```

As it is the LTS version of 12.04 isn't it supposed to work for 5 years? What can I do?

OK, did sudo apt-get update, there were no error messages, closed terminal and ran Update Manager again, this time it worked OK. Many thanks.

Comment: Try after changing in Download Mirror in Software & Updates.

Comment: There is no version 0.156.14.16 of `update-manager` in that directory. There is, however, a version 0.156.14.17. Did you do a `sudo apt-get update` first?

Comment: no, I just used update manager as usual. I will do a sudo apt-get update from terminal and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't run a `sudo apt-get update` in a while (or used tools that implicitly do that). Now the old version of the package has been replaced by a new one, but your system doesn't yet know about it. So `sudo apt-get update` is all that is needed.